# Mocking HTTP request (POST request) in Scala (using requests-scala)

Tags: scala

I am using requests-scala module to make HTTP requests as shown below:

```
object AEMUtility {
    ....
    def getJWTToken() {
    ....
    val response = requests.post(
      s"$imsExp/ims/exchange/jwt/",
      headers = Map(
        "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ),
      params = Map(
        "client_id" -> clientId,
        "client_secret" -> clientSecret,
        "jwt_token" -> token
      )
    )
    }
}
```

I want to mock the post request function for writing a Unit test by:
checking the arguments passed in the Mock function and returning a dummy response.

Is there a way to mock installed dependency in scala?

I tried :

```
"authorize" should "return JWT token if request is valid" in {
    val postMock = mock[requests.post]

  }
```

but this gives me error:
`Cannot resolve symbol post`

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is because `requests.post` is an instance of Requester ([see in source code](https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/requests-scala/blob/master/requests/src/requests/Requester.scala#L27)), `mock` expects a type parameter. You can't pass an object to it, you can mock its classes, traits, etc. So what you should probably do is trying to mock the case class:

```scala
val requester = mock[requests.Requester]
```

Or the `BaseSession` trait, which contains the `post`, `get` and other methods.

```scala
val session = mock[requests.BaseSession]
```

Or the `Session` case class, which is the implementation of the `BaseSession` trait.

```scala
val session = mock[requests.Session]
```

I'm not sure anyways, the library doesn't look test-friendly to me.

Comment: Hmm I see. Btw @AminMal, can you give an example where we can mock behaviour of post request? Based on its body and parameters and return a response accordingly?

Comment: @ShivamSahil Testing the behavior of post request is not something you should do, it’s something that the library should take care of (and they have done it), however, if you want to do some fake api call, in my opinion, you can create a wrapper class with the appropriate methods (post, put, etc.,), and mock that class.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse I am not going to test post behaviour, can you show a sample snippet about wrapper thing you talked about ? that would be really helpful!